# No Matching function to call C++

Tags: c++, function, pointers, reference, call

I have 2 classes TreeManager and TreeProducerBase. I am getting an error in passing an object of TTree( which is a class to make trees) to a function in TreeProducerBase from TreeManagerconstructor.
Note : I have defined tree as

```
TTree *tree_
```

Function call :

```
tpb.initialize(&tree_);
```

Here, tpb is an object of TreeproducerBase class.

This is the function that is being called.

```
void initialize(TTree &tree_)
```

It shows the error as follows:

```
error: no matching function for call to 'TreeProducerBase::initialize(TTree*&)'
```

Where am I doing wrong?

Comment: why is this tagged `python`?

Comment: Please show us relevant parts of your code

Comment: Post the code (or a simplified version of it). We can't help you with just that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are trying to pass pointer-to-pointer-to-TTree to a function that expects reference-to-TTree. Try redeclare it like

```
void initialize(TTree* &tree_);
```

Invokation will look like

```
tpb.initialize(tree_);
```

And then you can initialize outer pointer via simple assignment:

```
void initialize(TTree* &tree_) {
    tree_ = new TTree(); // or smth else
}
```